# how do i put a blanket over my character

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

so I have this scene where my character is supposed to be in a bed. but I can't get the blanket to go on top of the character like she's laying under it. I tried rigging it but that didn't really work

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18K9RtUYvHA3t7IKgIJsp7TmP-zp3tkdy/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a second bone that will influence the rest of the blanket, otherwise the only bone you've created will have full control on the vertices of its group, even on the ones that are part of the group at a very low weight.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To invert the vertex group, duplicate it then in *Weight Paint mode > Weights > Invert*:

[image]

Comment: can i also use 3 bones? :D

Comment: as much as you want but bone price has dramatically increased  :/

Comment: This damn Putin! He is guilty for that price explosion....!!!!! Even bones for a free software....I cannot believe...who stops this guy!?

Comment: yes I've heard he's doing it for bones  :/  empties are getting cheaper though, time to buy some

Comment: And suzannas? how are the prices developing for suzannas? I am thinking about investing in lot's of suzannas....

Comment: yes Suzanne seems to be the last NFTs craziness, Kim Kardashian has bought thousands from what I head

Comment: Dang!!!! BOUGHT 5000..!!!! Maybe in a few weeks i am richer than Jeff B. :D

Comment: ive never seen a comment chain this funny on this website. also how do i make a bone have the exact opposite influence as the first like picture #2 shows?

Comment: @desperrrr, yes we are the Laurel & Hardy of BSE. I've edited my answer